# how to read data line by line in python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a textfile  which is filled with data like follows:

```
#n
44026533495303941500076737402297403862946691

#e
6969696

#f
37243759787836627691897628674719248256836857
```

In the end, I want to know the numbers saved with the variables n, e, f

I tried to read it line by line, but the datastream  gives me only letter by letter 
My code was following:

```
file = open(sys.argv[2]).read() # for getting file
for line  in file:
    print(line)   # but it gives letter for letter
```

My idea was to take for example

```
n = file[1]
e = file[5]
```

Comment: how have you tried to parse the file?

Comment: *I tried to read it line by line, but the datastream gives me only letter by letter*. Can you share your code please? Because normal iteration over a file will give you data line by line, so you are doing something odd there.

Comment: I shared,  I hope it shows, what I mean

Comment: `read` returns a `str` string of characters. When you say `for line in file:` you're actually getting `for character in string:`

Answer (score 1):

Close, but no cigar.

You should get rid of the `.read()`, [it reads the whole file](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).
Here is what you were probably aiming for...

```
file = open(sys.argv[2])  # no .read() please
for line in file:
    print(line)   # now it gives the line

file.close() # don't forget to release the resource!
```

... but this is what you really want

```
with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        print(line)
```

By using the `with` keyword, you don't have to remember to close the resource! ([here's a tutorial on it](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python)).

Also if you specify `'r'` in the `open`, it's a little more obvious what you intend to do with the file. Not crucial but recommended.

Comment: Leaving out the `r` opens the file for reading. That's the default and it's well understood.